# como usar nlsM minpack R

Tags: r

Tengo estos datos:

```
A   xo   x   y    yo    p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4  s1   s2    s3      s4
1   1.7  1.7 0.45 0.45   1  0   0   0    0.45 #N/A  #N/A    #N/A
1   1.7  2.7 2.49 0.45   1  0   0   0    0.45 #N/A  #N/A    #N/A
2   1.7  1.7 0.48 0.48   0  1   0   0    0.45 0.48  #N/A    #N/A
2   1.7  2.7 3.49 0.48   0  1   0   0    0.45 0.48  #N/A    #N/A 
3   1.7  1.7 0.58 0.58   0  0   1   0    0.45 0.48  0.58    #N/A
3   1.7  2.7 2.19 0.58   0  0   1   0    0.45 0.48  0.58    #N/A
```

Y quería  traducir el siguiente script de SAS a R:

```
proc model data=five method=MARQUARDT maxiter=1000; 

yo=p1S1+p2S2+...+p&maxi S&maxi;
y=yo*EXP(-(b12)*x**-(b13))/EXP(-(b12)*xo**-(b13))

fit y /converge=0.001 estdata=start outpredict out=resinicial outest=params dw dwprob;
outvars num_parc y yo x xo resid pred actual truque id;

run; %mend fits;
```

En R estoy usando el paquete min.pack haciendo lo siguiente:

```
library(minpack.lm)
Gfun=function(x,t,G0,t0){ 
  y=yo*exp(-(x[1])*x^-(x[2]))/exp(-(x[1])*xo^-(x[2]))
  return(y)
}

Yresid <- function(parS, yObs, x,yo,xo) { # Resíduos
  YObs-Yfun(parS,x=x,yo=yo,xo=xo)
}

parStart=c(3.405398, 0.40278)


nls.out <- nls.lm(par=parStart, fn = Yresid, YObs = Y, X=X,Yo=Yo,Xo=Xo,
                  control = nls.lm.control(nprint=1,
                                           ftol = .Machine$double.eps,
                                           ptol = .Machine$double.eps,
                                           maxfev=10000, maxiter = 500))
```

Pero me da el siguiente error :

> Error in t^-(x[2]) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

y además no sé como indicar la función de `yo=p1S1+p2S2+...+p&maxi S&maxi`

Comment: Mencionas un error, ¿podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el mensaje que recibes?

Comment: Sí ya está editada. Gracias @Patricio Moracho

Comment: Sin un ejemplo reproducible, lo único que puedo decirte, es que el error se produce por que se está combinando en una operación binaria un elemento numérico con otro que no lo es. Por ejemplo, algo como esto `1 + "uno"` te dará un error similar. Revisa dentro de la función `Gfun` si `x[2]` siempre es numérico.